# Combine consecutive observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

My problem is to combine two consecutive observables and return it as a single observable. There are a lot of combine operators in rxjs but documentation just confused me.

Here is a working solution I came up with. However, I feel like it isn't the right way to do it for readability.

```
const observableGetId = () => {SomeFunctionBody};
const observableGetDataWithId = (id) => {SomeAnotherFunctionBody};

observableGetId.pipe(
  mergeMap((id) => {
    return forkJoin([
      of(id),
      observableGetDataWithId(id)
    ])
  })
).subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result[0]) // id
  console.log(result[1]) // data
})
```

Is there a better operator or some other way to do this?

Comment: Note that AngularJS and Angular are two very different frameworks. I've removed AngularJS since most people do not use rxjs with that framework, but you should be careful. Also, it looks like your question does not even pertain to Angular at all, so you may not even need either tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to get `{id: processedId, data: data for relevant Id}` in a simple way.

You can do following,

```
const observableGetId = () => {SomeFunctionBody};
const observableGetDataWithId = (id) => {SomeAnotherFunctionBody};

observableGetId.pipe(
  mergeMap((id) => observableGetDataWithId(id).pipe(
    map(res => {return {id: id, data: res}})
)))
.subscribe((result) => {
    // console.log(result.id, result.data);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with **[`SwitchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)**, which is actually an efficient way while you can also add error handling part with help of **[`catchError`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch)**.

```
  const observableGetId = () => {SomeFunctionBody};
  const observableGetDataWithId = (id) => {SomeAnotherFunctionBody};

  observableGetId.pipe(
      switchMap((id)=> observableGetDataWithId(id).pipe(
        map(res => {return {id: id, data: res}}))
      catchError(err => of(null)))
   ).subscribe((result) => {
           console.log(result.id, result.data);
   }, error => 
         console.log("Error Description");
   );
```

Also look at the below article for better understanding about RXJS operators.

- https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/when-to-use-switchmap-dfe84ac5a1ff

Happy Coding.. :)